# Encountering 'Attribute 'cfBundleVersion' Error: Expected String, Received Integer' while uploading IPA

Tags: ios, react-native, bitrise

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload my IPA to the App Store. The error message indicates a problem with the datatype of the cfBundleVersion attribute, stating that it's incorrect. Strangely, this was working fine until yesterday.

It's the error log:

```
2024-02-09 22:16:35.839  INFO: ContentDelivery version 2.141.101 (141101).
2024-02-09 22:16:35.852  INFO: Show Progress: Contacting Apple Services…
2024-02-09 22:16:36.729 *** Error: Error [REDACTED]ing '/Users/vagrant/deploy/[REDACTED] - Development.ipa'.
2024-02-09 22:16:36.730 *** Error: An attribute in the provided entity has the wrong type Unexpected json type provided for attribute 'cfBundleVersion'. Expected a STRING but got INTEGER (ID: xxxxx) (409)
 {
NSLocalizedDescription = "An attribute in the provided entity has the wrong type";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unexpected json type provided for attribute 'cfBundleVersion'. Expected a STRING but got INTEGER (ID: xxxxx)";
"original_server_error" =     {
    code = "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.TYPE";
    detail = "Unexpected json type provided for attribute 'cfBundleVersion'. Expected a STRING but got INTEGER";
    id = "xxxxx",
    source = {
        pointer = "/data/attributes/cfBundleVersion";
    };
    status = 409;
    title = "An attribute in the provided entity has the wrong type";
};
}
Uploading IPA failed: exit status 1
```

Here's the relevant snippet from my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>74</string>
```

I've built the iOS app using React Native and deployed it via Bitrise.

Any insights into why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!